# UI is not get updated with data after success

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, breeze

I am new to Breeze and i am creating a sample to learn. I am facing an issue. I have create a **datacontext.js** in which i have added the breeze code to get data from service like below

```
sample.factory('datacontext', ['breeze', 'Q', '$timeout', '$q', function (breeze, q, timeout, $q) {
configureBreeze();
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("/breeze/ProductsBreeze");
manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

var datacontext = {
    metadataStore: manager.metadataStore,
    getTodoLists: getTodoLists
};
function getTodoLists(onsuccess) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("GetAllProducts");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then(onsuccess);

};
return datacontext;
//function getSucceeded(data) {
//    return data.results;
//}
function configureBreeze() {
    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

    // configure to use camelCase
    breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
}
}]);
```

now in **getTodoLists** i am passing a callback **onsuccess**. Here is my controller

```
sample.controller('todoBreeze', ['datacontext', '$scope', '$log', function (datacontext, $scope, log) {
$scope.heading = "Hello World";
$scope.Products = [];
datacontext.getTodoLists(function (data) {
    $scope.Products = data.results;
    log.info($scope.Products);

});
$scope.editProduct = function (pid, index) {
};
$scope.deleteProduct = function (pid, index) {

};
}]);
```

now the problem is that its show that i have two records (showing in console) in my array after completed the request but UI is not get updated if i use

```
<span>{{Products.length}}</span>
```

but if i call `$scope.$apply()` after request completed then its works fine.

Can you please let me know what is the error in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**See UPDATE below.**

The $scope.$apply() function is used to put code back into the "AngularJS world".

When using third party libraries like you are doing, that is exactly what you need to use to execute the code inside AngularJS digest cycle.
When you use AngularJS services that have a callback, they already call $apply() in the background and put the code back into AngularJS digest cycle.

In your case, you created your own service and are passing a callback to it in your controller. When that callback is called, you are already outside of an AngularJS digest cycle and therefore AngularJS will not notice that the scope changed. Calling the $apply function sets the code back to AngularJS digest cycle and let's AngularJS see that the scope changed.

A more detailed guide to $scope.$apply can be found at http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

So, you can change your factory code like this to include the $apply call:

```
sample.factory('datacontext', ['breeze', 'Q', '$timeout', '$q', '$rootScope', function (breeze, q, timeout, $q, $scope) {
configureBreeze();
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("/breeze/ProductsBreeze");
manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

var datacontext = {
    metadataStore: manager.metadataStore,
    getTodoLists: getTodoLists
};
function getTodoLists(onsuccess) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("GetAllProducts");
    manager.executeQuery(query).then($rootScope.$apply(onsuccess));
};
return datacontext;
```

That way you don't need to call it on every controller that uses your service.

**UPDATE:**

I was misguided by your sentence regarding the $scope.$apply(). That is why it is better to provide a working example, so we can play around with it.

I think the problem is that you are changing the reference that the $scope.Products variable is set.
When you initialize it with

```
$scope.Products = []
```

you create an array A and make Products refer to that array. Then you change the array that Products is referencing when you make in your callback

```
$scope.Products = data.results;
```

Try to go through the data.results array and push it to the Products array and see if that helps.

Comment: ERROR : Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- datacontext